# Which is faster , interacting with a database or using a file system for input output

Tags: database, file

I was wondering what threshold of data volume may determine whether to use a database or a simple file I/O, assuming that fresh data needs to be handled quite frequently.

Edit: There is no multi-threading in my application. Data needs to be stored and then retrieved sequentially and at this point I am not really worried about anyone else accessing the data/data safety.
Given this backdrop is there still any advantage to using databases over files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends and you probably should consider other factors as well.
If you use a database, there is an overhead for transactions, security, index management etc. on the one hand. On the other hand you can get caching (which *could* significantly speed up your application) and better performance for random access, if you have a lot of data. In a multithreaded environment I suggest using a database because of a property implemented locking mechanism.
Flat files are OK for really simple and small data. Do you really need to open and close them so often?

Comment: I have data which will be updated every few seconds, sometimes a few times in a sec, i need to store that data (not all of it, i can delete past data ) and perform a few conditions on that data at a repeat of a certain time frame , say a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexes on your table correctly then I think it would be better to use database instead of file system to get a better performance. Also to include that if your data in the database is going to be million of records then also the performance will not be affected when compared to file system with that much amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a database is prefered and in this case id suggest to use sqlite database insted of sql server and mysql as data is small.

Comment: can i use sqlite with c sharp

Comment: @user3404790 Yes you can. Just create a sqlite file and put it somewhere in a map. Then check out msdnaa or other sites to see how to connect to it using web.config :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would say DB. You are writing and reading and thats what DBs are good at.
On the flip side if you are holding a tiny amount of data thats alot of over head for not much data

also depends on licensing etc. a file will be alot quicker